# PostgreSQL: How to use -> and ->> to search SQL JSON?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below is the json in my 'details' column in a postgreSQL DB. I am trying to do a login check to return the username which matches the password.

```json
{
  "id":"11a8581b-b56f-426e-92f6-a426ba635b98",
  "firstName":"Ryan",
  "lastName":"Bob",
  "username":"ryan",
  "address":"Flat 7, 8 Clisssld Road, London, N16 9AB",
  "email":"ryan@abc.com",
  "password":"$s0$e0801$M/lNYD/JsVN4FoOjs7BwBA==$+C3+A9lAYPMd1YM0FsSbaIzw0wFito4OSEvSrMM/34k="
}
```

```
SELECT details -> 'username' 
FROM users WHERE 
details -> 'password' = '$s0$e0801$M/lNYD/JsVN4FoOjs7BwBA==$+C3+A9lAYPMd1YM0FsSbaIzw0wFito4OSEvSrMM/34k=';
```

Comment: This is an odd way to write a password auth.. *to properly generate the hash from the secret (plaintext password), one needs to have already read the value from the database (to access the salt and such)*. And accepting the raw hash as the authentication input is equivalent to not hashing passwords at all :|

Comment: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Comment: You would be better off normalizing the data by using regular database columns rather than a `jsonb`.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL provides two native operators `->` and `->>` to help you query JSON data.

- The operator `->` returns JSON object field as JSON.
- The operator `->>` returns JSON object field as text.

I think [this link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) could be really helpful in your case.